# Bounded type parameters cannot be used in interfaces that require parent class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to do the following in Java using generics:

```
public class MyType {
    public void printBase(Collection<Base> bases) {
        for (Base base : bases) {
            System.out.println(base.toString());
        }
    }

    public <A extends Base> void myMethod(Collection<A> things) {
        // ...
        printBases(things); // Error here
        // ...
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:

`The method printBases(Collection<Base>) in the type MyType is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<A>).`

In this case, however, `A extends Base` so A is a Base. Shouldn't this method call be legal? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collection<A>` does not extend `Collection<Base>` even though `A` extends `Base`.
So it is absolutely normal to see this error at compile time.

Given that you cannot change the definition of `printBase`, here is a possible workaround.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

class Base {

}

class A extends Base {

}

public class MyType {
    public void printBase(Collection<Base> bases) {
        for (Base base : bases) {
            System.out.println(base.toString());
        }
    }

    public <A extends Base> void myMethod(Collection<A> things) {
        Collection<Base> lst = new ArrayList<Base>();
        lst.addAll(things);
        printBase(lst);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your answer. I wasn't thinking about it like that, but it really makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @Max OK, suggested some workaround. I guess you figured it out yourself too.

Answer (score 4):

Generic types are invariant so the type used for `Collection<Base>` is not compatible with `Collection<A>`. You could use an upper bound generic type for the `bases` argument

```
public void printBase(Collection<? extends Base> bases) {
```

Comment: In my example this would work, but unfortunately, I do not have access to the `printBase` source code.